# Inefficient SQL Search Query - Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, search, query-optimization

My logic in this query is right (well im 80% sure it is). but its been running for 2h 23min and still going, was wondering if some one could maybe help me make this run a bit more efficiently as i don't think its that intense of a query

```
SELECT b.bridge_no, COUNT(*) AS comment_cnt
  FROM iacd_asset b INNER JOIN iacd_note c
    ON REGEXP_LIKE(c.comments, '(^|\W)BN' || b.bridge_no || '(\W|$)', 'i')
inner join ncr_note e on c.note_id=e.note_id
inner join ncr f on e.ncr_id=f.ncr_id
inner join ncr_iac g on f.ncr_id=g.ncr_id
 WHERE c.create_dt >= date'2015-01-01'
   AND c.create_dt < date'2015-03-12' 
   AND length(b.bridge_no) > 1
   AND g.scheme in (1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, and about 10 more values)
 GROUP BY b.bridge_no
 ORDER BY comment_cnt;
```

in short the query should be making a bunch of joins, and then filtering the joined table by schemes (g.scheme in....) , and then parsing the notes field for anything with BN in it.

PLAN TABLE, ok i have never used one before, but i believe this is the plan table

```
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| OPERATION        | OPTIONS        | OBJECT_OWNER | OBJECT_NAME      | OBJECT_ALIAS | OBJECT_INSTANCE | OBJECT_TYPE    | OPTIMIZER | ID | PARENT_ID | DEPTH | POSITION | COST    | CARDINALITY | BYTES       | CPU_COST        | IO_COST | TEMP_SPACE | ACCESS_PREDICATES           | FILTER_PREDICATES                                                               | PROJECTION                                                                              | TIME | QBLOCK_NAME  |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| SELECT STATEMENT |                |              |                  |              |                 |                | ALL_ROWS  | 0  |           | 0     | 281,503  | 281,503 | 40          | 4,480       | 148,378,917,975 | 215,677 |            |                             |                                                                                 |                                                                                         | 458  |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| SORT             | ORDER BY       |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 1  | 0         | 1     | 1        | 281,503 | 40          | 4,480       | 148,378,917,975 | 215,677 |            |                             |                                                                                 | (#keys=1) COUNT(*)[22], "B"."BRIDGE_NO"[NUMBER,22]                                      | 458  | SEL$81719215 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| HASH             | GROUP BY       |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 2  | 1         | 2     | 1        | 281,503 | 40          | 4,480       | 148,378,917,975 | 215,677 |            |                             |                                                                                 | (#keys=1) "B"."BRIDGE_NO"[NUMBER,22], COUNT(*)[22]                                      | 458  |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| HASH JOIN        |                |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 3  | 2         | 3     | 1        | 281,497 | 16,084      | 1,801,408   | 148,366,537,976 | 215,677 | 24,126,000 | "G"."NCR_ID"="F"."NCR_ID"   |                                                                                 | (#keys=1) "B"."BRIDGE_NO"[NUMBER,22]                                                    | 458  |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| HASH JOIN        |                |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 4  | 3         | 4     | 1        | 96,996  | 209,778     | 21,607,134  | 13,549,630,814  | 90,985  | 22,725,000 | "E"."NCR_ID"="F"."NCR_ID"   |                                                                                 | (#keys=1) "F"."NCR_ID"[NUMBER,22], "B"."BRIDGE_NO"[NUMBER,22]                           | 158  |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| HASH JOIN        |                |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 5  | 4         | 5     | 1        | 42,595  | 208,419     | 20,216,643  | 5,484,063,163   | 40,162  | 9,839,000  | "C"."NOTE_ID"="E"."NOTE_ID" | REGEXP_LIKE ("C"."COMMENTS",'(^|\W)BN'||TO_CHAR("B"."BRIDGE_NO")||'(\W|$)','i') | (#keys=1) "B"."BRIDGE_NO"[NUMBER,22], "E"."NCR_ID"[NUMBER,22]                           | 70   |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| PARTITION RANGE  | SINGLE         |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 6  | 5         | 6     | 1        | 1,039   | 104,603     | 8,577,446   | 62,280,224      | 1,011   |            |                             |                                                                                 | "C"."NOTE_ID"[NUMBER,22], "C"."COMMENTS"[VARCHAR2,4000]                                 | 2    |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           | IACDB        | IACD_NOTE        | C@SEL$1      | 2               | TABLE          | ANALYZED  | 7  | 6         | 7     | 1        | 1,039   | 104,603     | 8,577,446   | 62,280,224      | 1,011   |            |                             | "C"."CREATE_DATE"<TO_DATE(' 2014-12-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')     | "C"."NOTE_ID"[NUMBER,22], "C"."COMMENTS"[VARCHAR2,4000]                                 | 2    | SEL$81719215 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| MERGE JOIN       | CARTESIAN      |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 8  | 5         | 6     | 2        | 24,267  | 12,268,270  | 184,024,050 | 2,780,501,758   | 23,033  |            |                             |                                                                                 | (#keys=0) "B"."BRIDGE_NO"[NUMBER,22], "E"."NCR_ID"[NUMBER,22], "E"."NOTE_ID"[NUMBER,22] | 40   |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           | IACDB        | IACD_ASSET       | B@SEL$1      | 1               | TABLE          | ANALYZED  | 9  | 8         | 7     | 1        | 7       | 40          | 160         | 560,542         | 7       |            |                             | LENGTH(TO_CHAR("B"."BRIDGE_NO"))>1                                              | "B"."BRIDGE_NO"[NUMBER,22]                                                              | 1    | SEL$81719215 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| BUFFER           | SORT           |              |                  |              |                 |                |           | 10 | 8         | 7     | 2        | 24,259  | 308,248     | 3,390,728   | 2,779,941,216   | 23,026  |            |                             |                                                                                 | (#keys=0) "E"."NCR_ID"[NUMBER,22], "E"."NOTE_ID"[NUMBER,22]                             | 40   |              |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           | IACDB        | IACD_NCR_NOTE    | E@SEL$2      | 4               | TABLE          | ANALYZED  | 11 | 10        | 8     | 1        | 606     | 308,248     | 3,390,728   | 69,498,530      | 576     |            |                             |                                                                                 | "E"."NCR_ID"[NUMBER,22], "E"."NOTE_ID"[NUMBER,22]                                       | 1    | SEL$81719215 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| INDEX            | FAST FULL SCAN | IACDB        | PK_IACDNCR_NCRID | F@SEL$3      |                 | INDEX (UNIQUE) | ANALYZED  | 12 | 4         | 5     | 2        | 31,763  | 22,838,996  | 137,033,976 | 3,248,120,913   | 30,322  |            |                             |                                                                                 | "F"."NCR_ID"[NUMBER,22]                                                                 | 52   | SEL$81719215 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
| TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           | IACDB        | IACD_NCR_IAC     | G@SEL$4      | 8               | TABLE          | ANALYZED  | 13 | 3         | 4     | 2        | 181,461 | 1,731,062   | 15,579,558  | 134,407,812,606 | 121,833 |            |                             | ALL THE SCHEMES CHCECKS                                                         | "G"."NCR_ID"[NUMBER,22]                                                                 | 295  | SEL$81719215 |
+------------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------+----+-----------+-------+----------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+---------+------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+--------------+
```

Hopefully thats legible enough

interms of indexes i assume only the fields that are being sorted is importent
crate_dt is not indexed
scheme id is indexed

Maybe my order in query is wrong...

Comment: Post the explain plan. What are the indexes involved?

Comment: What is the query plan?  What indexes are available?  Which predicates are selective?  How selective are they?

Comment: updated main post with extra info, in terms of the predicate, the only selective one is really the schemes which there are about 50 values to choose from. the other is the date range and the parsing of BN, in the comments field which i guess in theory could be a lot?

Answer (score 2):

The plan shows you're doing FULL TABLE SCAN of IACD_NOTE and IACD_ASSET, and then doing a CARETESIAN join of them, because you have provided *no criteria* for linking one record in IACD_ASSET to a set of records in IACD_NOTE.

That's not my definition of a non-intense query, and the eye-popping values for CPU cost bear that out.

You need to replace this ..,

```
FROM iacd_asset b INNER JOIN iacd_note c
ON REGEXP_LIKE(c.comments, '(^|\W)BN' || b.bridge_no || '(\W|$)', 'i')
```

... with an actual join on indexed columns.  It would be helpful if Notes were linked to Assets by a foreign key of BRIDGE_NO or similar.  I don't know your data model. Then you can use that regex as an additional filter in the WHERE clause.

Also you join to three further tables, to get to something which allows an additional filter on SCHEME.  Again, I don't know your data model but this seems pretty inefficient.

Unfortunately this is the sort of tuning which relies on domain knowledge.  Fixing this query requires understanding of the data - its volume, distribution and skew, the data model itself and the business logic your query implements.  This is way beyond the scope of the advice we can offer in StackOverflow.

---

One thing to consider, but it is a big decision would be to index the comments with a free text index.  However, that has lots of ramifications (especially space and database admin). [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/toc.htm).

Comment: So if i take out the REGEXP_LIKE function, to dump just all the values of the the joins the query takes about 4min.....

If i remove the joins and just do the REGEXP_LIKE function on the two tables it takes about 7 min....

So i would have through if i could structure my query to first do the joins, and then parse through the results.... it shouldn't take that long? right?